# troubleshooting dns resolution, packet dropping, and dig/nslookup

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, firewall, curl

I've been trying to troubleshoot an issue where using a curl lookup command takes a long time (sometimes) and is quick some other time.

TL;DR
Question: how do i troubleshoot further.

Connecting directly to an ip-address has no issues.

I've tried two different locations, multiple machines (RPi, debian vm, Windows10).

I've tried to set nameservers to both 1.1.1.1 and to 8.8.8.8 with the same result

i've changed the /etc/resolv.conf so that it contains (and yes. i've writeprotected it)

```
options timeout:1
```

So now it nolongertakes 5 seconds before it succeeds in dns_resolution.. but 1.00xx seconds (sometimes) and sometimes 0.00xxx seconds.

For me it first looked like a firewall dropping packets issue or a ipv6-try issue. however i've disabled ipv6 on the machines, with no luck.

I've used this command to do the lookups:

```
while :; do curl --max-time 10 -w "time_namelookup: %{time_namelookup}, time_connect: %{time_connect}, time_appconnect: %{time_appconnect}, time_pretransfer: %{time_pretransfer}, time_redirect: %{time_redirect}, time_starttransfer: %{time_starttransfer}, time_total: %{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null -s "https://www.google.com"; sleep 1; done
```

and here is some sample result:

```
time_namelookup: 1.059151, time_connect: 1.083971, time_appconnect: 1.129219, time_pretransfer: 1.129803, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 1.191138, time_total: 1.198772
time_namelookup: 1.058956, time_connect: 1.084363, time_appconnect: 1.130112, time_pretransfer: 1.131392, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 1.291702, time_total: 1.300107
time_namelookup: 1.057719, time_connect: 1.083355, time_appconnect: 1.128083, time_pretransfer: 1.128726, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 1.190859, time_total: 1.198635
time_namelookup: 0.018382, time_connect: 0.043042, time_appconnect: 0.077228, time_pretransfer: 0.077517, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 0.142618, time_total: 0.150624
time_namelookup: 1.058276, time_connect: 1.082821, time_appconnect: 1.127496, time_pretransfer: 1.128083, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 1.188930, time_total: 1.197614
time_namelookup: 0.023630, time_connect: 0.047877, time_appconnect: 0.079810, time_pretransfer: 0.080053, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 0.136007, time_total: 0.141614
time_namelookup: 0.018607, time_connect: 0.043160, time_appconnect: 0.079620, time_pretransfer: 0.079966, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 0.139617, time_total: 0.145728
time_namelookup: 1.059191, time_connect: 1.084436, time_appconnect: 1.127247, time_pretransfer: 1.127825, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 1.189962, time_total: 1.199934
time_namelookup: 1.058040, time_connect: 1.083303, time_appconnect: 1.127172, time_pretransfer: 1.128314, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 1.194481, time_total: 1.202276
time_namelookup: 0.018539, time_connect: 0.043664, time_appconnect: 0.079772, time_pretransfer: 0.080074, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 0.141406, time_total: 0.147358
time_namelookup: 1.060180, time_connect: 1.084996, time_appconnect: 1.130302, time_pretransfer: 1.131054, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 1.197778, time_total: 1.205363
time_namelookup: 0.031891, time_connect: 0.058458, time_appconnect: 0.097752, time_pretransfer: 0.098055, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 0.157533, time_total: 0.188634
time_namelookup: 1.059059, time_connect: 1.083472, time_appconnect: 1.126565, time_pretransfer: 1.127196, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 1.189149, time_total: 1.195730
time_namelookup: 0.023647, time_connect: 0.048197, time_appconnect: 0.082277, time_pretransfer: 0.082772, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 0.143120, time_total: 0.149757
time_namelookup: 0.017073, time_connect: 0.041658, time_appconnect: 0.081927, time_pretransfer: 0.082310, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 0.144873, time_total: 0.152739
time_namelookup: 0.017251, time_connect: 0.042056, time_appconnect: 0.079905, time_pretransfer: 0.080475, time_redirect: 0.000000, time_starttransfer: 0.141332, time_total: 0.147886
```

Doing a dig command however is VERY fast:

```
 $ dig @dns.google google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u8-Raspbian <<>> @dns.google google.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13497
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             221     IN      A       172.217.19.78

;; Query time: 25 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 16 10:44:24 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55



$ dig @1.1.1.1 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u8-Raspbian <<>> @1.1.1.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54885
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             65      IN      A       142.250.147.101
google.com.             65      IN      A       142.250.147.113
google.com.             65      IN      A       142.250.147.138
google.com.             65      IN      A       142.250.147.139
google.com.             65      IN      A       142.250.147.100
google.com.             65      IN      A       142.250.147.102

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 16 10:44:33 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135
```

This is similar across multiple internet connection outgoing originating from Denmark

I also had some findings where there was no issues at all. dns resolution was fast etc on one device while there was issues on a other device running though the same ASN-no but different sub ip-range.

MTR/traceroute shows no signs of issues. im just not sure why it goes to 100.x.x.x ip address, but there must be some kind of routing. This does not happen on the other connections

```
                         My traceroute  [v0.92]
devicename (xx.x.x.xxx)                          2023-02-16T11:50:47+0000
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                               Packets               Pings
 Host                        Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. xx.x.x.x                  0.0%   211    3.0   2.2   1.4   8.3   0.8
 2. 31.3.xx.xxx               0.0%   211    1.7   2.1   1.4   7.3   0.7
 3. 100.64.x.xxx              0.0%   211    6.8   8.1   6.1  37.8   3.5
 4. 94.127.48.17              1.4%   211    7.4   8.3   6.1  48.0   6.3
 5. xe-2-1-0-311.alb2nqe10.d  0.0%   211    6.9   9.4   6.3  46.4   6.3
 6. ae0-0.stkm2nqp7.se.ip.td  0.0%   211   15.7  16.4  14.8  35.1   2.8
 7. 72.14.214.162             0.0%   211   17.4  17.1  15.3  33.4   2.7
 8. 209.85.254.3              0.0%   211   16.1  17.0  15.4  48.7   3.8
 9. 108.170.253.181           0.9%   211   18.4  17.8  15.2  60.1   6.2
10. 108.170.227.249          10.0%   211   20.6  17.8  15.4  41.2   4.2
    209.85.246.61
11. 142.251.51.215            2.8%   211   26.7  26.4  24.0  54.7   4.6
    209.85.248.7
12. 142.250.214.184           1.4%   210   44.6  25.9  23.7  48.6   4.1
    142.251.239.219
13. 172.253.70.203            0.5%   210   25.1  24.8  23.9  28.2   0.6
    142.250.46.23
14. ???
15. ???
16. ???
17. ???
18. ???
19. ???
20. ???
21. ???
22. ???
23. rd-in-f139.1e100.net     38.3%   210   24.8  25.0  24.1  30.7   0.7
```

Traceroute shows that it goes to one actual ip address and then to a bogus (100.x.x.x) ip adddress.

```
traceroute to google.com (142.250.147.102), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  xx.x.x.x (xx.x.x.x)  2.436 ms  2.624 ms  2.510 ms
 2  31.3.xx.xxx (31.3.xx.xxx)  2.392 ms  2.941 ms  2.834 ms
 3  100.64.x.xxx (100.64.x.xxx)  6.451 ms  6.629 ms  6.519 ms
 4  94.127.48.17 (94.127.48.17)  6.403 ms  6.600 ms  6.762 ms
 5  xe-2-1-0-311.alb2nqe10.dk.ip.tdc.net (87.48.169.225)  6.653 ms  8.382 ms  8.074 ms
 6  ae0-0.stkm2nqp7.se.ip.tdc.net (83.88.2.128)  16.956 ms  16.121 ms  15.401 ms
 7  72.14.214.162 (72.14.214.162)  16.827 ms  16.741 ms  16.650 ms
 8  * * *
 9  108.170.254.33 (108.170.254.33)  17.564 ms 209.85.242.10 (209.85.242.10)  16.346 ms 108.170.253.161 (108.170.253.161)  17.412 ms
10  108.170.254.38 (108.170.254.38)  17.255 ms 108.170.253.182 (108.170.253.182)  17.105 ms 108.170.254.54 (108.170.254.54)  16.645 ms
11  209.85.246.61 (209.85.246.61)  16.484 ms 72.14.234.107 (72.14.234.107)  17.352 ms 142.250.235.228 (142.250.235.228)  17.045 ms
12  108.170.236.41 (108.170.236.41)  26.269 ms  26.088 ms 142.251.51.217 (142.251.51.217)  26.110 ms
13  142.251.239.219 (142.251.239.219)  24.352 ms 142.250.214.198 (142.250.214.198)  26.021 ms 142.250.214.178 (142.250.214.178)  26.295 ms
14  142.250.214.229 (142.250.214.229)  25.056 ms 142.250.215.9 (142.250.215.9)  25.494 ms 142.250.229.93 (142.250.229.93)  25.310 ms
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * rd-in-f102.1e100.net (142.250.147.102)  25.956 ms *
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the output 'dig' made only an A request (i.e. one dns request), and there's mtr in ipv4 mode with its RTT time.
Suppose that in case with curl, there were two dns requests: for ipv4 and for ipv6 (A and AAAA). Have you tried to run that curl example with '-4' option to compare its 'time_namelookup' for ipv4 resolv only?